# Horrible quality on web scraped image using rvest

Tags: r, image, web-scraping, rvest

I scraped an image as follows:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
url = 'http://x.yupoo.com/photos/05941188/albums'
web = read_html(url)
```

Now I need to consider the nodes. I'll take the `extract2()` function to select the precise nodes:

```
gianni = html_nodes (web, '.showindex__gallerycardwrap')
ugo = gianni %>%  extract2(1) %>%  html_nodes('img') %>%  html_attr('src')
```

Now I download the images. I'm doing it with the `download.file` function, which requires me to build a new object `protocol` in order to have a complete URL string:

```
protocol = 'http:'
scarica = download.file(paste0(url,ugo[1], destfile = 'imm.jpg', method = 'wininet')
```

When I see the image it looks like this, which is obviously not what I expected in terms of quality:

[image: web scrape img gianni]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the link with "url", creating it with "http:" does the trick for me:

```
download.file(paste0("http:",ugo[1]),destfile = "imm.jpg", method = 'wininet',mode='wb')
```

[better quality image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaIvy.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, what actually makes the difference is the option 'mode' = wb, i don't know why but now it works!